# Перевод кода из Pascal в С++

Tags: c++, pascal

Помогите перевести код на С++

```
var
a: array [1..100] of Integer;
n,i,j,x: Integer;
begin
  repeat 
    write('N [1..',High(a),']');
    readLn(n)
  until n in [1..High(a)]; //вводим n, пока он не будет принадлежать диапазону 1..100
  for i:=1 to n do read(a[i]);// вводим n элементов массива
  write('A ='); for i:=1 to n do write(' ',a[i]); writeLn; //выводиим элементы
  for i:=1 to n-1 do if not odd(a[i]) then //проверка на чётность
    for j:=i+1 to n do if not odd(a[j]) then
    if a[i]>a[j] then begin //сортировка
      x:=a[i]; a[i]:=a[j]; a[j]:=x;
    end;
  write('A''='); for i:=1 to n do write(' ',a[i]);//вывод
end.
```

Answer (score -5):

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
```

int main() {

`int a[100], n;
while (true) {
    cout << "N [1..100]\n";
    cin >> n;
    if (n <= 100 && n > 0) { break; }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << "a[" << i << "]=";
    cin >> a[i];
}
cout << "A =[";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { cout << a[i] << ','; }
cout << "]\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    if (a[i] % 2) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (a[j] % 2&&a[i]>a[j]) {
                int x = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << "A =[";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { cout << a[i] << ','; } cout<<"]\n";
return 0;
}`

Comment: Не поощряйте лентяев, выполняя за них домашнее задание.

Comment: если бы оно ещё правильно  было написано...